# SVN checking out new files from repo that others have added

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I have checked out a SVN repo and work on it locally all is fine.  If my colleague also checks out the repo and they can also work on it fine.

When my colleague creates a new file, adds it to the repo and commits it.  Running update does not automatically download the additional file.

Deleting the local repo and checking it out a second gets the additional file.

What command do I need to execute to ensure that when running update it does get any additional files?

I am using the Tortoise shell and subversion SVN.   The end application is an electronics cad package, Altium, so we normally only use checkout, commit and update commands.

Comment: Does this happen all the time? Now that you have fresh working copy maybe the problem will not happen again.

Comment: wow that was quick - yeah it happen consistantly, all of the other files are updated to the latest, it just does not pull across any new files created since the repo was first checked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update tortoise to latest version.  To fix your existing working copy, instead of choosing "Update", choose "Update to revision"  and change the depth to "Fully recursive".  You'll have to do this once on the latest version, or you could stay on the version you have now and do it every time...

[Source](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#incompleteupdate)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like some setting going horribly wrong on your SVN server, update should most definitely add / delete files in your local copy based on what's committed to the server!

Answer (score 0):

To update all the files (from the current directory downwards):

```
svn up
```